# Find function in String outputs garbage when no string matches

Tags: c++, string, function, output

I have following code :-

```
    string name = "hello world";
    size_t find = name.find("world");

    if (find != string::npos) {
        cout<<"match found at "<<find;
    }
    else{
        cout<<find;
    }
```

This program works fine and print 6 output as expected.

But if I change it to `size_t find = name.find('\n');`
It prints garbage value as `18446744073709551615`. Does find function prints Garbage value when it does not find the matched string ??

Comment: The value is not "garbage" -- it is `string::npos`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It prints garbage value as 18446744073709551615. Does find function prints Garbage value when it does not find the matched string ??

No, `std::string::find()` doesn't print. Instead you're printing out the return value of it. And it's not garbage value, just the value of `std::basic_string::npos`.

See the definition of [`std::basic_string::npos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos):

> ```
> static const size_type npos = -1;
> ```
>
> This is a special value equal to the maximum value representable by the type `size_type`.

Answer (score 3):

Quote from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

> Return Value
>
> The position of the first character of the first match.
> **If no matches were found, the function returns string::npos.**
>
> size_t is an unsigned integral type (the same as member type
> string::size_type).

Your function therefore prints std::string::npos, which for example in the MSVS std library implementation is

```
basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>::npos =
        (typename basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type)(-1);
```

Which is the maximum unsigned int value on your 64bit system: 18,446,744,073,709,551,615, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx

You could change your code to

```
string name = "hello world";
size_t find = name.find("world");

if (find != string::npos) {
    cout<<"match found at "<<find;
}
else {
    cout<<"match not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your else statement to print "not found".

Your code is printing the return value from `find`, which is `std::string::npos` when not found.